# Ways to include context in the score generated against the document

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, cosine-similarity, milvus

I have a usecase with me. If you have any ideas or approaches on how to solve it (partially or fully) please let me know.

I am using vector database `milvus` for my application. Currently, the database contains columns `content` and `embeddings`. For each chunk (a chunk generally contains 2-3 lines of text), i am generating embeddings and storing them in `embeddings` column.

Now, coming to the use case. I have documents that speak about onboarding, how to do discord onboarding, are stored in vector db. I will query vector db `find all docs that contains slack onboarding`.

Based on the cosine similarity between the query embedding and the list of docs embedding, vector db picks the docs that has minimum distance between them.

So, i got list of docs which has onboarding and discord onboarding and a high score along with it. I am not aware of how the score is calculated. When i say high score assigned to each document listed in the resultant set, the scores are 83.5, 85.5 approx.

Since my query contains the term  `onboarding`, i got all onboarding docs. The query also contains `slack`. Is it possible to penalise all docs from the resultant set that doesn't have slack along with onboarding with it.

If so, i wish to know how can it be done.